# Arraylist - how to get a specific element/name?

Tags: java, arraylist

I've tried to search the WWW but failed to find an answer. Couldn't find one here either.

Here's my question:
How do I get a specific name(element?) from a Customer in an ArrayList?
I'm imagining it looks something like this:

```
ArrayList<Customer> list = new ArrayList();

String name = list.get(2) // which would return the Customer at 2's place.
```

But what if I want to search for a customer by name, lets say a customer named Alex? How do I do that?

Bonus question: How do I then delete that customer?

Comment: Is the list containing object of type `Customer` or `String`. The two lines of code that you have provide contradict each other.

Comment: What is the reason behind search? you want to know index? you want to know list has object? etc., based on these you can use different techniques.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have said this isn't all that efficient and a HashMap will give you fast lookup. But if you must iterate over the list you would do it like this:

```
    String targetName = "Jane";
    Customer result = null;
    for (Customer c : list) {
        if (targetName.equals(c.getName())) {
            result = c;
            break;
        }
    }
```

If you need to remove an item from a list while iterating over it you need to use an iterator.

```
    String targetName = "Jane";
    List<Customer> list = new ArrayList<Customer>();
    Iterator<Customer> iter = list.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Customer c = iter.next();
        if (targetName.equals(c.getName())) {
            iter.remove();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your are going to have to iterate through your array using something like this in a function call.

```
void int HasName(string name){
    for(int i=0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        String s = list.get(i).getName();
        //search the string
        if(name.equals(s)) {
            return i
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```

If you really need to search by name consider looking into HashMap.

Answer (score 1):

With an ArrayList, you have to loop... If you can, use a Map (HashMap, TreeMap) to quickly find an element.
This works if you always seek by name, for example. (use name as key of the map)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to explicitly do what you want, unless you want to iterate through the whole collection, comparing the desired name to the current one.  If you want this type of functionality, you could try a Map such as `HashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

Implement equals and hashcode for Customer object. Use customer name attribute for this.

Use ArrayList.indexof to find the index of the element. use the remove method in Arraylist to remove the object by index.